# Visual Studio / IIS Crashing using axapta businessconnectornet on asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, axapta

I'm trying to replace an old Axapta ComConnector with something more reliable (always using Asp.Net/C#).

Now I'm trying to [follow this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb931177%28v=ax.10%29.aspx) that teach how to use *"Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet.dll"*.

On a console application using the suggested code i can call "Logon" (to more that one server) without experience any problem.

I copied the same code and library to an asp.net website (doing the necessary edits) and when i try to call "Logon" the WebServer **crashes** (both on *IIS 6* or *Visual Studio 2010/2005*).

Have someone experienced the same problem?
Have you managed to resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
System event log records:

> .NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.5456 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (79C9EABE) (80131506)

and

> Nome dell'applicazione che ha generato l'errore: WebDev.WebServer20.exe, versione:10.0.40219.1, timestamp: 0x4d5f3456
>   Nome del modulo che ha generato l'errore: mscorwks.dll, versione: 2.0.50727.5456, timestamp:0x4ef6c72d
>   Codice eccezione: 0xc0000005
>   Offset errore 0x0000ee3b

Comment: When it crashes, is it throwing an exception? What's happening when you attach a debugger?

Comment: The problem is that it isn't throwing an exception (i've put a try/catch on "Logon"), just crashing _w3wp_ or _WebDev.WebServer_ or directly _Visual Studio_ if i'm on debug or attached to the process.

Comment: I haven't used the library you mention, but I would guess there is a problem with permissions because it works ok with a console app and not in IIS (runs under a different security context). If you exhaust all the simple solutions, you could use the WinDbg or adplus (Windows Debugging Tools) tool to create a memory dump when the crash happens then open the dump file with WinDbg and use the !analyze -v command to see if it gives any insight. GL

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Perhaps I'm not familiar with these tools, then i think i'll take debug of IIS/VS crash as last resource... :)

Comment: also, take a look in your server event logs (AOS's and IIS), you may get an insight

Comment: What operating system are you using.  I suspect this might be a case of a 32-bit assembly trying to be loaded by a x64 IIS process.  Why are you using IIS 6?

Comment: My development OS is Windows 7 64bit and i use IIS6 because the current server for this task has Windows Server 2003... And then i think it runs on x86 configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem replacing the web application with a windows service because the BusinessConnectorNet seems to be not allowed on an ASP.Net environment.